# Add Annotation to map from another View

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, mkmapview, mkannotation, appdelegate

I'm trying to call `plotParkingLots` from my AppDelegate as I want it to be called first when the app starts (and then every x seconds which I will implement later).

`plotParkingLots` works fine if I call it through my MapViewController's `viewDidLoad`, but when I call it from AppDelegate, it doesn't work.

I know that it is called but when I switch to my map view, no annotation is shown!

MapViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

#define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController <MKMapViewDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

- (void)plotParkingLots;

@end
```

MapViewController.m

```
- (void)plotParkingLots {
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http:/localhost/testes/parking.json"];
    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    if (jsonData == nil) {
        UIAlertView *alertBox = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Erro de conexão" message: @"Não foi possível retornar os dados dos estacionamentos" delegate: self cancelButtonTitle: @"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertBox show];
    }
    else {
        NSError *error;
        NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];

        NSArray *parkings = [json objectForKey:@"parkings"];
        for (NSDictionary * p in parkings) {
            Parking *annotation = [[Parking alloc] initWithDictionary:p];
            [_mapView addAnnotation:annotation];
        }
    }
 }

- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    static NSString *identifier = @"Parking";
    if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[Parking class]]) {
        MKPinAnnotationView *annotationView = (MKPinAnnotationView *) [_mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:identifier];
        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:identifier];
        } else {
            annotationView.annotation = annotation;
        }

        annotationView.enabled = YES;
        annotationView.canShowCallout = YES;
        annotationView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"car.png"];

        return annotationView;
    }

    return nil;    
}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [[MapViewController alloc] plotParkingLots];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not talking to the MapViewController that is displayed to the user. In your AppDelegate you momentarily allocation a MapViewController, plot the parking lots, then abandon that MapViewController and never use it again.

You'll need to keep a handle to that controller so that when the user presses something to make that viewcontroller get displayed it is the same one that has just plotted the parking lots.

Comment: I understood what you said, but have no idea on how to do that. Can i use a singleton the MapViewController? Would that be a good solution?

Comment: Where do you create the MapViewController to show it to the user? If it doesn't get shown until a user clicks a button, why would you want to load it up with data? They might not even go to that screen. If they do go to that screen you must be creating a MapViewController and then displaying it. You could fetch the data after your app has finished starting up and then only pass it across when you init it for real.